# Error could not convert string to float en clasificador Naive-Bayes

Tags: python

Necesito crear un clasificador Naive-Bayes que, dada una muestra, clasifique si una persona es hombre o mujer.

Este es el fichero con los datos que tengo que usar para entrenarlo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJjxhp0AsPAckOpwTXaULU6sixqtb3lZ/view?usp=sharing

La muestra me da los siguientes datos:

Estatura(cm): 182.88

Peso(kg):58.97

Longitud del pie (cm):20.32

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


fichero = open ('trainingdata.csv', 'r')
datos = pd.read_csv (fichero)

x = datos.iloc [:,[1,2,3]].values
y= datos.iloc [:, 0].values

x_entreno, x_prueba = train_test_split (datos)
y_entreno = x_entreno ["Sexo"]
y_prueba = x_prueba ["Sexo"]

nb_clasificador= GaussianNB()
nb_clasificador.fit (x_entreno, y_entreno)

y_predicciones = nb_clasificador.predict (x_entreno)

print ('Precisión en test de entrenamiento: {:.2f}'.format(nb_clasificador.score (x_entreno, y_entreno)))
print ('Precisión en test de set: {:.2f}'.format(nb_clasificador.score (x_prueba, y_prueba)))

print (nb_clasificador.predict [182.88 , 58.97, 20.32])
```

Cuando llega a la línea nb_clasificador.fit (x_entreno, y_entreno) es cuando me salta el error could not convert string to float: 'Masculino' y no entiendo el por qué ni como arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque está intentando entrenar un modelo de clasificación Naive Bayes con datos de texto. El algoritmo Naive Bayes espera que los datos de entrada sean valores numéricos, no cadenas de texto como 'Masculino'.

Para solucionar este problema, deberá convertir las etiquetas de género en valores numéricos. Por ejemplo, puede asignar 1 a 'Masculino' y 0 a 'Femenino'. Luego, puede usar el método fit del clasificador para entrenar el modelo con los datos de entrenamiento numéricos. A continuación, podrá hacer predicciones con el método predict del clasificador.